# Run script using Invoke-AzVMRunCommand in VM? Passing parameter problem

Tags: linux, bash, azure, powershell

**Problem description:** When you create parameters as object and pass to VM-Windows-PS all is good you can have name=value, but on linux VM that is not the case, you get only values in unknown order.

**Preparation:**

- Source: Your PC: Windows: Login Azure in powershell.
- Target: Azure: Have Linux VM, in my case ubuntu18.

**Code:**

```
echo '#!/bin/bash' >>.\msgtst.sh
echo 'echo test: $1 $2 $3 $4 $5 $6' >>.\msgtst.sh
$Script_paramz = @{"lgs" = "SARB"; "Event"="a1001"; "LogName"="xSystem" }
Invoke-AzVMRunCommand -ResourceGroupName VMResourceGroup -VMName LinuxVMName -ScriptPath ".\msgtst.sh" -CommandId RunShellScript -Parameter $Script_paramz -Verbose
```

**Tries:**

```
$Script_paramz = @{"lgs" = "ARB"; "Event"="1001"; "LogName"="System" }
```

[stdout]
test: ARB System 1001

```
$Script_paramz = @{"lgs" = "SARB"; "Event"="a1001"; "LogName"="xSystem" }
```

[stdout]
test: SARB xSystem a1001

```
$Script_paramz = @{"lgs" = "1SARB"; "Event"="C1001"; "LogName"="bSystem" }
```

[stdout]
test: 1SARB bSystem C1001

```
$Script_paramz = @{"par1" = "val1"; "par2"="val2"; "par3"="val3"; "par4"="val4"; "par5"="val5"; "par6"="val6" }
```

[stdout]
test: val3 val6 val1 val2 val4 val5

**Powershell output: $Script_paramz**

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
par3                           val3
par6                           val6
par1                           val1
par2                           val2
par4                           val4
par5                           val5
```

**Does anyone have a solution to this?**

Edit: answer how i solved this, still would like to know if there is possibility to see parameter names correctly.

$Script_paramz = @{"par1" = "par1=val1"; "par2"="par2=val2"; "par3"="par3=val3"}

```
#!/bin/bash
par2=''; par1=''; par3='';
for var in "$@"
do
   IFS='=' read -r -a array <<< "$var"
   export "${array[0]}"="${array[1]}"
done
echo $par1, $par2, $par3
```

[stdout]  val1, val2, val3

Comment: Please provide output of `echo test: "$@"` instead of `echo test: $1 $2 $3 $4 $5 $6`

Comment: echo test: $@ $*

Comment: test: val6 val2 val5 val1 val4 val3 val6 val2 val5 val1 val4 val3

Comment: i could ofcource make value as "par1" = "par1=val1" pair, but it means i would need to use exception for linux script, i am using this for windows also, no big deal but want to understand how this works

Comment: is it night sleep or actually your suggestion to use $@  led me to solution of parsing parameters, if anyone knows how to get parameter names from powershell i would like to hear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**$Script_paramz** is a HashTable. Order is not kept by default in HashTable implementation. One approach you can try is to use OrderedDictionary from [Powershell HashTable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_hash_tables?view=powershell-6).

```
$Script_paramz = [ordered]@{"par1" = "val1"; "par2"="val2"; "par3"="val3"; "par4"="val4"; "par5"="val5"; "par6"="val6" }
```

So the result in powershell will be:

```
PS C:\Users\fielu> echo $Script_paramz 

Name                           Value
----                           -----
par1                           val1
par2                           val2
par3                           val3
par4                           val4
par5                           val5
par6                           val6
```

Comment: Thanks, i have tried to order it by other means, this helps, but i want to match name=value somehow, if noone gives a solution then i will mark this as answer.

Comment: @DaliusV did you get this to work in the end? I am getting same issue where parameters from Powershell to bash is going in wrong order